# fscanf Segmentation fault - C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am getting a segmentation fault error while trying to use fscanf to read from a file into a string, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    char temp[100];
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
    }

    memset(temp, 0, strlen(temp));

    while (fscanf(fp,"%s", temp)==1)
    {

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Contents of input file? (Does it perhaps have a string longer than 99 characters?)

Comment: In addition to other comments and answers: `memset(temp, 0, strlen(temp));` is not needed at all as you `fscan` into `temp` anyway.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I still think it is a good idea to have at least one null terminator at the beginning of a `char` array, for safety.

Comment: @BetaCarotin What "safety" does `memset(temp, 0, strlen(temp))` provide?  If `fscanf(fp,"%s", temp)==1` is not true the contents of `temp` are not specified to retain the zeros.  If anything, code should use a wdith limit `fscanf(fp,"%99s", temp)` for "safety".

Comment: @chux None. What I am saying is that if there is a `char` array, there should be a `0` at the front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strlen` function does something along these lines:

```
int strlen(char *s)
{
    int len = 0;
    while(*s++) len++;
    return len;
}
```

In other words, it will return the location of the first null character it encounters.  If you haven't already initialized your string, then the pointer will probably get incremented out of the array bounds and into some other part of the process' memory in search of the null terminator (which makes it segfault).

To address this issue, replace the argument to `memset` with `sizeof(temp)`.

Comment: While you indeed explain why the code has a segmentation fault, imho you should elaborate and demonstrate how to fix the problem.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

In the call to `strlen(temp)`, `temp` has undefined contents.

Instead, use `char temp[100] = {0};` and don't use `memset` at all.

Comment: Note that `strlen(temp)` will return zero in this case, so `memset` won't do anything. Furthermore, `temp` doesn't need to be initialized before calling `fscanf`.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Thanks, I explicitly mentioned removing the call to `memset`.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar Which I did in response to a comment.

Comment: Note: `char temp[100] = {};` won't work in ISO C. `char temp[100] = {0};` would be the portable way.

Answer (score 1):

It is problem related to strlen function, you can fix it like this:

```
int main()
{
    char temp[100];
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
    }

    memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp)); //use sizeof instead of strlen is enough

    while (fscanf(fp,"%s", temp)==1)
    {

    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Get rid of `memset(temp, 0, strlen(temp));`

Replace `char temp[100];` with  `char temp[100] = {};`

Comment: You copied my answer and didn't even bother to include the reason why the code is invalid.

Comment: You don't actually need to replace the declaration since `fscanf` doesn't care about the contents.